# terminate & launch other node from code

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a ROS way to terminate and launch another node from one node's code?

For launching example in python, it's possible by doing something like this w/o using ROS:

```
import os
os.system('roslaunch turtlebot_navigation_ours amcl_customized.launch')
```

Any way to do the same in an official way in ROS?

How about terminating as well? If a node run as "respawn = true" receives "shutdown" msg/service request then shuts down itself? Better idea?

---

Update) I thought I'd better describe a situation when I need this...There is a node that gets to consume higher CPU in a process of time (eventually CPU load reaches 12.0 or above although it's not supposed to do so). And I found that restarting makes it stay calmer and still functions. Besides debugging that node itself, it would be nicer if I can just work around the issue for now by restarting the node.

---

Update-2) Found [similar QA thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/501/spawn-and-kill-nodes-from-nodessmach) and `roslaunch.scriptapi` might be good as well for launching from `python` (I'm sure the argument for `ROSLaunch.launch` is `roslaunch.core.Node` instead of `roslaunch.Node` as in [API doc](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roslaunch/html/roslaunch.scriptapi-pysrc.html#ROSLaunch.launch)).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12260/terminate-&-launch-other-node-from-code/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-12-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, of course, you can start a node from another node using your favorite process management API.
In ROS, you also have [rosspawn](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosspawn) which will provide this kind of service.

However, it seems to me that what you want to achieve does not really fit well with the ROS framework. When using component oriented frameworks, the general idea is to start all the services at the beginning (using a roslaunch file for instance) and stating nodes relations and configurations using the ROS parameters.
Then no nodes should be killed before the whole system is shutdown.

Then monitoring tools and/or interactive tools should just be launched from outside, using rosrun.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-12-08**:
@Thomas, If I understand him correctly I think he just want's to periodically restart a node that is leaking resources. And if that part of his system that he's restarting is stateless/part of a pipeline (e.g. an edge detector node) there should be no ill effects other than the restart delay AFAICT.

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2011-12-08**:
Sorry, my post probably was not clear enough: all the roslaunch files I have seen so far are launching services without having, at any moment, to restart or stop them. Having to do that proably means that your code is not reentrant which is something one should avoid, that's all ;)

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-12-08**:
@Thomas thanks. rosspawn seems good and now I'm giving a shot at it. Meanwhile do you think of any source about component oriented frameworks requires all services begin at the same time? I'm just curious to know more about the concept.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-12-08**:
Sounds like rosspawn will do exactly what he wants. (I'm not sure I understand the comment that what he want's to do doesn't fit well.)

**Comment by [vinay_kumar28](https://answers.ros.org/users/29262/vinay_kumar28/) on 2017-02-20**:
can you tell me how it will be done in rosjava? i mean which api in rosjava is used to run another node?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-02-20**:
@vinay_kumar28 please don't use comment section to ask a whole new question. Open a new one.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2021-12-20**:
@Asomerville Does rosspawn allow for nodes(ran via launch files)to be autonomously killed and restarted when certain conditions are met?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-12-20**:
@distro please don't use comment section to ask a new question. To the worst, your question in the comment section doesn't get attention.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've encountered this problem as well. On our robot, we have ROS set to autoboot on power-up. At this point, it boots into a "minimal" state in which only a few nodes are running until we receive a connection to an external network. At that point, it will launch the rest of the ROS nodes. Why we do this isn't really important, but here's HOW we do it... Just a warning, it's fairly complex.

Our whole autoboot/control system is based on a Bash/C++ interface. You are able to pipe the output of a C++ program to a Bash script and read the output. To do this, your C++ program must simply output to stdout and Bash can read it. Here's a quick example of what I mean:

control.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    while(1)
    {
      if(guiNotConnected())
      {
        cout << "Connected" << endl;
      }
      sleep(1);
    }
}
```

control.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

function cpp_func {

    /home/robot/scripts/control

}
while read line; do
    if [ "$line" == "Connected" ]; then
        roslaunch robot_launch rest_of_ros.launch
    fi
done < <(cpp_func)
```

In the above example, "/home/robot/scripts/control" represents the location of the c++ executable on the filesystem. The reason it's wrapped in a Bash function is because Bash doesn't allow you to pipe an executable directly in to the function. I.E. "`done << /home/robot/scripts/control`" is not allowed. That's why the executable is wrapped in the Bash function cpp_func.

This allows us to execute any functions we want (start, kill, restart, etc.) on any node we want. As long as you expect an output in your Bash script, you can handle any ROS commandline processes from that one control.bash script. Just a note, you cannot send commands back to the c++ program using this method.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-12-08**:
I think you can do `/home/robot/scripts/control | while read line`  and make things a little simpler.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-08**:
I've edited my answer to also address this question.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-12-08**:
@DimitriProsser Wow this seems interesting, and I think it's not as complex as you mentioned. Quick question: why do you need "/home/robot/scripts/control"?

**Comment by [zf](https://answers.ros.org/users/22939/zf/) on 2016-01-06**:
I can't understand "/home/robot/scripts/control", is this the path where "control.cpp" locates or some other path?

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2021-12-20**:
@DimitriProsser Does your method allow for nodes(ran via launch files)to be autonomously killed and restarted when certain conditions are met?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just had the same problem and was stunned to see how difficult it was to find a simple example for this basic task.
So I added a minimal code example to the roslaunch wiki page:

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage

---

Originally posted by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) with karma: 391 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes](https://answers.ros.org/users/2719/johannes/) on 2014-07-15**:
Is there a way not just to start a single node, instead start an whole launch file?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-20**:
@Johannes it looks like there might be api entries for that but they aren't currently implemented: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/scriptapi.py#L74

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-20**:
Though you can start a launch file bypassing the api `import roslaunch; args = ['roslaunch', 'my_package', 'foo.launch']; roslaunch.main(args)`- but it blocks and doesn't have the stop/is_alive methods.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2021-12-20**:
@lucasw sorry I'm still confused, does your method allow for nodes(ran via launch files)to be autonomously killed and restarted when certain conditions are met?